# Change color of the text cell based on its value

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to change the color of the text of the cells in the UITableView.

When I'm trying to do conditional formatting using `if`, it doesn't work.

Here is the code I'm trying:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
        return nomearray.count;
}

- (void)tableView: (UITableView*)tableView willDisplayCell: (UITableViewCell*)cell forRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{

cell.textLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;


if(indexPath.row % 2 == 0) {

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(240/255.0) green:(240/255.0) blue:(240/255.0) alpha:1];}

else {
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];}

}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}


if (risco == 1) {[cell.textLabel setTextColor: [UIColor colorWithRed:(60/255.0) green:(169/255.0) blue:(133/255.0) alpha:1]];} else {

    if (risco == 2) {[cell.textLabel setTextColor: [UIColor colorWithRed:(255/255.0) green:(200/255.0) blue:(0/255.0) alpha:1]];} else {

        if (risco == 3) {[cell.textLabel setTextColor: [UIColor colorWithRed:(150/255.0) green:(50/255.0) blue:(50/255.0) alpha:1]];}}}



 cell.textLabel.text = [nomearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;
```

}

Comment: And where is this code? Inside what method?

Comment: risco is a integer variable, witch can assume 3 values, 1, 2 or 3. What i want is the color of the text in the cells change based on the value of this var (risco)

Comment: i put the code above in - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath, but doesn`t work. I`m tried the - (void)tableView: (UITableView*)tableView willDisplayCell: (UITableViewCell*)cell forRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath*)indexPath method too!

Comment: Is your cell custom? And, if it isn't, you're using text label or detail text label to introduce the text? I think the code of the whole method would be useful to answer.

Comment: i will edit the post and put the entire method. Just a sec! And thank you for your reply!

Comment: I would recommend you to implement textLabel's color changes in willDisplayCell as the table view sends this message to its delegate's willDisplayCell just before it uses cell to draw a row, thereby permitting the delegate to customize the cell object before it is displayed. This method gives the delegate a chance to override state-based properties set earlier by the table view, such as selection and background color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is your if condition is not satisfying Because integer values is not setting up properly. So just set the property of risco integer and then check, Did you try?

Comment: you`re absolutely right man!! the problem was in the setting up properly the risco (risk) var! thank you so much!!!